# Mac OS X : Display a picture in a simple window

Tags: objective-c, macos, window, image

I want to display a picture store in the disk in a simple window and I didn't succeed to do it.
I might be very simple normally, no?
Thanks for any help...
Jérôme

PS: I want to do it by programming.

Answer (score 0):

create a image object using `initWithContentsOfURL:` drag a imageview or nsbutton. using method `-setImage` set a image.